# APIs hitting 400 error with response "unrecognised configuration" in 1 pod of kubernetes

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes

I rewrote the path of actual API URL in my nodejs file by using proxy-middleware package, `/restservices/api/disaster/v1/events` to `/api/events` to hide the actual url and instead of calling the apis with lgws of different environments, we are calling with CDP GRM edge URLs, like instead of `actual lgw/api/events` we call `actual-grm-url/api/events`.
Issue - when deployed one pod gives response with data its request URL - "grm-edge-url/api/events" where grm-edge-url has podnumber:portnumber ; whereas its failing and giving response as 400 bad request with body respose as "unrecognised configuration" and its request URL - similar to other with different podnumber:portnumber .

Tested in postman - which actual URLs and grm edge URLs - giving response except for the other pod that giving 400 error.